# Pandigital exponent solution?

Tags: exponentiation

I don't have [Reviewing C++ By Alex Maurea](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055703079X) book. But someone in facebook post a question from this book which is following

[image]

You can see the puzzle at [page 542 **problem 29**](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=IT_RAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA542&lpg=PA542&dq=A%20pandigital%20number%20makes%20use%20of%20the%20digits%201%20through%209%20at%20least%20once&source=bl&ots=umSI2iPD0x&sig=_-aMvWYQR7P0p7ouyEpi8Zo6l4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sjK0UoO-O4K0rAevUQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pandigital%20number%20makes%20use%20of%20the%20digits%201%20&f=false).

Now I think the answer should be log<sub>2</sub>123456798. Am I right or I am tackling the question wrong way?

Comment: Your answer would be right if $k$ could be any real number, not just a positive integer (which I presume it must be; otherwise the problem would be trivial).

Answer (score 1):

You tackled in a wrong way. You must check the powers of 2 and find the smallest one, such that the last 9 digits are pairwise different and greater than 0.

By the way, the solution is

k=955

with ending digits

247315968

I found it with the following PARI-program

? k=1;gef=0;while(gef==0,k=k+1;n=Mod(2^k,10^9);u=component(n,2);x=vector(9);null
=0;while(u>0,j=u-truncate(u/10)$*$10;if(j>0,x[j]=x[j]+1);if(j==0,null=1);u=truncat
e(u/10));if((null==0)$*$(vecmin(x)>0),gef=1));print(k)

Comment: As Peter Kosinar stated, k must be a natural number, otherwise the problem makes no sense.

Comment: Well I don't know the `PARI` language but can you give some nipticks/hint about the algorithm you used. It's christmas. :)

Comment: I calcaulated 2^k, took it modulo 10^9 to seperate the last 9 digits and counted the digits occuring with the array x. The digits are calculated by repeating division by 10. If the vector conatins no zeros and the digit 0 does not occur, the desired number is found.